# React: How to save value from async function and use later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, frontend

I have an async function that calls an api getting me the current role of a user. Later on I want to attach that role to a variable. Here's my code

```
const getRole = async () => {
        const response = await roleService.getRole();
        const roles = await response.role
        return roles
    }
     ...........

 const currentRole = getRole() //I want this to be the value from return roles
```

I'm new to react and having trouble with this. How can I set `currentRole` to the value in `return roles`?

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: Since you're in react, the most likely thing you'll do once you have the value is set state. So perhaps instead of `return roles` you'll do `setRoles(roles)`

Comment: const response = await roleService.getRole(); return response.role

Answer (score 2):

I would opt to save the information that you got from the API on a state

```
const [roles, setRoles] = useState();

const getRole = async () => {
        const response = await roleService.getRole();
        const roles = await response.role
        setRoles(roles);
    }
```

you can call the gerRole function on a useEffect like this

```
useEffect(() => {
getRole();
}, []);
```

or you can call the getRole function on a button click

```
<button onClick={getRole}>Click me to get roles</button>
```